# unable to spot syntax error in function signature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following function -

```
def add (*nums)
  nums.reduce(:+)
end

def subtract(first, *rest)
  first - rest.reduce(:+)
end

def calculate(*nums, options)
  first = nums.first
  rest = nums.reverse.drop(1)
  add(*nums) if options.size == 0
end
```

The following is the error I receive when invoking the function -

> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' def calculate(*nums,
>   options={}) ^

What is the error in my syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your splat and your options too, you just have to sort it out by hand:

```
def calculate(*nums)
  options = nums.last.is_a?(Hash) ? nums.pop : { }
  #...
```

Then you can say `calculate(1, 2, 3)` and `calculate(1, 2, :size => 0)` without difficulty. Of course, this assumes that a Hash isn't a valid value for something in `nums`.

Comment: Yup, why didnt I think of that ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a default parameter after splatted parameter. This creates an ambiguity for the parser. For example:

```
calculate 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Should 4 go to `nums` or be assigned to `options`?

A couple of options are available

#### Remove default parameter for options

```
def calculate(*nums, options)
  # implementation
end

calculate 1, 2, 3, add: true # options
calculate 1, 2, 3, {} # no options
```

#### Remove the splat

```
def calculate(nums, options = {})
  # implementation
end

calculate [1, 2, 3], add: true # options
calculate [1, 2, 3] # no options
```

#### Keep both, but do more work

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682607/125816) by @muistooshort

Comment: The function will be invoked as calculate(1,2,3,4,:add true)

Comment: then remove default value for options, it should solve the problem.

Comment: I also have to cater for the possibility where no value is provided for options, what happens in that case ?

Comment: Then you can remove the splat and pass an array explicitly.

Comment: I am trying to solve a problem on rubymonk, and this is the last question on this link - http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/69-new-lesson. I have also edited my post to add my full code